# Helper function involving std::move

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding

codereview would not allow hypothetical code, so I am posting here instead.  Given this code:

```
#include <string>

struct foo {
    std::string a, b;
    foo (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) : a(a), b(b) { }
};

template <typename T> void bar (const T&) { }
template <typename T> void bar (T&&) { }

void execute (const foo& f) {
    // etc...
    bar(f.a);
    // etc...
    bar(f.b);
    // etc...
    bar(f);
    // etc...
}

void execute (foo&& f) {
    // etc...
    bar(std::move(f.a));
    // etc...
    bar(std::move(f.b));
    // etc...
    bar(std::move(f));
    // etc...
}

int main() {}
```

I want to write `execute_helper` to handle both execute overloads, since they are identical except for the `std::move` calls. Here is what I have, and I want to know if I did it correctly. I'm unsure about using `T&` and `T` in my `check_move` overloads, and whether passing `T` by value worsens the time complexity or not.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    std::string a, b;
    foo (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) : a(a), b(b) { }
};

template <typename T> void bar (const T&) { }
template <typename T> void bar (T&&) { }

template <typename T>
T check_move (const foo&, T& t) { std::cout << "std::move not called.\n";  return t; }

template <typename T>
T&& check_move (foo&&, T t) { std::cout << "std::move called.\n";  return std::move(t); }

template <typename F>
void execute_helper (F&& f) {
//   etc...
    bar(check_move(std::forward<F>(f), f.a));
//   etc...
    bar(check_move(std::forward<F>(f), f.b));
//   etc...
    bar(check_move(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<F>(f)));
    // etc...   
}

void execute (const foo& f) {
    execute_helper(f);
}

void execute (foo&& f) {
    execute_helper(std::forward<foo>(f));
}

// Test
foo make_foo() {
    return foo("hello", "bye");
}

int main() {
    foo f("hello", "bye");
    execute(f);
    execute(make_foo());
}
```

Output:

```
std::move not called.
std::move not called.
std::move not called.
std::move called.
std::move called.
std::move called.
```

Comment: In this case `execute(f);` entity cannot be std::move'd as there is other variable ( `f` here ) holding the entity.

Comment: I think `template<class U> void execute(U&& u) { bar(forward<U>(u.a)); bar(forward<U>(u.b)); bar(forward<U>(u.c)); }` should work.

Comment: `template<class U> void execute(U&& u) { bar(std::forward<U>(u).a); bar(std::forward<U>(u).b); bar(std::forward<U>(u)); }`?